# Auto sort rows in specific column and skip blank rows

Tags: excel, vba

**This is the code for provide column M with sheetNames excluded with these Names (sht1-sht9)::

`Public Sub Worksheet_Activate()
Const sht1 As String = "Main-test"
Const sht2 As String = "Data-list"
Const sht3 As String = "Report"
Const sht4 As String = "EmpList"
Const sht5 As String = "emp_intface"
Const sht6 As String = "sample"
Const sht7 As String = "SSSSSS"
Const sht8 As String = "log"
Const sht9 As String = "Report2"

Range("m:m").ClearContents


Dim S As Integer
For S = 1 To Worksheets.Count
With Worksheets("Report2")
Set ws = Worksheets(S)
If ws.Visible = True And _
  (ws.Name <> sht1) And (ws.Name <> sht2) And (ws.Name <> sht3) And (ws.Name <> sht5) And _
  (ws.Name <> sht4) And (ws.Name <> sht6) And (ws.Name <> sht7) And (ws.Name <> sht8) _
  And (ws.Name <> sht9) Then

.Cells(S, 13).Value = ws.Name
End If
End With

Next
End Sub`

****More Details to explain my problem :**

so these excluded SheetNames begain at first then the rest of sheets came at the last order after the excluded Sheets,so when this code run its make some blanks rows in Columns M ;becoz the order of sheets had been excluded ,**so what is the solution to move the SHeetNames from 10th or 11th row to the first blank row in Column M???`**

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `S` variable to increment the rows else you will get blanks if the `IF` condition is not satisfied. Try this

```
Dim S As Integer, R As Long

R = 1

For S = 1 To Worksheets.Count
    With Worksheets("Report2")
        Set ws = Worksheets(S)
        If ws.Visible = True And (ws.Name <> sht1) And (ws.Name <> sht2) _
        And (ws.Name <> sht3) And (ws.Name <> sht5) And (ws.Name <> sht4) _
        And (ws.Name <> sht6) And (ws.Name <> sht7) And (ws.Name <> sht8) _
        And (ws.Name <> sht9) Then
            .Cells(R, 13).Value = ws.Name
            R = R + 1
        End If
    End With
Next
```